# How do I create a work item type in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

How do I create a custom Work Item Type in TFS 2012? 
 e.g.) I want to create a type called "Support Request" , instead of just a bug or task etc.
 I have an XML Template file.

Regards,
Ang

Comment: Is there something specific that isnt working here. Otherwise this is well documented ie use witadmin to import/export your witd.

Comment: Don't forget that creating a work item type only is the beginning if you also want to have e. g. reports, or display them in project portal. We just went through the process (with TFS 2010). In hindsight, getting some external experience on this would have been far more effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download TFS 2012 Power Tools to get the process editor installed. Link: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f

Then take a look at this guide (it uses TFS 2010 - I think you can use it anyhow):
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=755