# How to distinguish data fix work items in TFS

Tags: tfs

I would like to distinguish Data Fixes from Bugs and Tasks in my TFS Work Items. I'm currently using the Agile workflow template and so only have Bugs, Tasks and Product Backlog Items as the available Work Items.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this, or would I have to create a custom Work Item as per this question: [How do I create a work item type in TFS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026132/how-do-i-create-a-work-item-type-in-tfs-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a new Story tagged with "DataFix". You can then create a query to get that dates out again.

It's not a bug as you have no failing test case. Everything else is just work that is represented as a story in the agile template. It's a little easyer to comprehend in the scrum template as the work item is not constrained to "story" and is instead just a backlog item.

Comment: To use tags I have to use the web interface to create the task (not the VS interface) and I cannot query on the tag, instead MS recommends adding a column and filtering: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn132606.aspx

Comment: Tags are fully supported in Visual Studio and MTM with Update 2. The recommendation on your link is to updtate both TFS and Visual Studio to the latest version.